# how to add 'required' attribute to input field based on other fields values

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html

I have these input fields:

```
<input class="text_field" id="ProfilePhoneNumber" phone-by-state="User.PhoneNumber" type="text" required/>

<div class="btn-group">
    <button multi-select="User.Notifications.Phone" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">
        Select Severities <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul multi-select-dropdown class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="NotificationsPhone_1"
                   ng-model="User.Notifications.Phone.High">
            <label for="NotificationsPhone_1">High</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="NotificationsPhone_2"
                   ng-model="User.Notifications.Phone.Medium">
            <label for="NotificationsPhone_2">Medium</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="NotificationsPhone_3"
                   ng-model="User.Notifications.Phone.Low">
            <label for="NotificationsPhone_3">Low</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div><input id="SMS" type="checkbox"
       ng-model="User.SMS.Enabled">SMS Enable
</div>
```

I want to remove the 'required' attribute from the ProfilePhoneNumber text field and make it required only if at least 1 of these other checkboxes are checked.

Can I do it through HTML? angular? jquery?
What is the best way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [`ng-required`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input) here

```
<input class="text_field" id="ProfilePhoneNumber" phone-by-state="User.PhoneNumber" type="text" 
    ng-required="User.Notifications.Phone.High == 1 || User.Notifications.Phone.Medium == 1 || User.Notifications.Phone.Low == 1 || User.SMS.Enabled == 1" />
```

`ng-required` will sets `required` attribute on the element if expression pass to `ng-required` sets to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use angularjs "ng-required"

```
<input class="text_field" id="ProfilePhoneNumber" phone-by-state="User.PhoneNumber" type="text" ng-required="User.Notifications.Phone.High || User.Notifications.Phone.Medium || User.Notifications.Phone.Low"/>

<div class="btn-group">
    <button multi-select="User.Notifications.Phone" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">
        Select Severities <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul multi-select-dropdown class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="NotificationsPhone_1"
                   ng-model="User.Notifications.Phone.High">
            <label for="NotificationsPhone_1">High</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="NotificationsPhone_2"
                   ng-model="User.Notifications.Phone.Medium">
            <label for="NotificationsPhone_2">Medium</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="NotificationsPhone_3"
                   ng-model="User.Notifications.Phone.Low">
            <label for="NotificationsPhone_3">Low</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You should change `|` to `||` operator. The `|` operator in angular is only useful for filters.